# Download file using ajax and asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, download

i need to download a file when user clicks on a link (no need to show progress or anything) but if an error occurred on the server (file not found or something) then a dialog with an error message will pop up. I am thinking ajax but how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need a resource on your server to deliver the file (I highly recommend a .ashx file if you're using .NET but you should be able to do it with an MVC controller too) and then, like you say, a web page with some javascript to make an AJAX call to the server resource.

If you do context.Response.BinaryWrite on the server, and make sure the file is loaded into memory as Bytes then you are good to go.